# Выдайте все трехзначные числа, которые делятся на 7, и у которых при этом сумма цифр также делится на 7

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, числа

Выдайте все трехзначные числа, которые  делятся на 7,  и у которых при этом сумма цифр также делится на 7. Входных данных у этого алгоритма нет.

Подскажите, как вписать входные данные, если их нет. По-моему, число нужно обозначить переменной, выделить из него цифры из разряда сотен, десятков и единиц. Далее их просуммировать и через  условие "сумма кратна 7 и само число кратно 7" вывести ответ.

Вот только с входными данными проблема

Comment: Задача ведь элементарная. Как раз для самых новичков в программировании. Задача, как понимаю, из школьного ГИА.
Входные данные - трехзначные числа(!)  =>  все числа от 100 до 999

Comment: @0xFFh, задача простейшая, знаю. Просто сначала немного струхнула, что нет входных данных, а сейчас уже разобралась.
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: потянулись студенты и школьнники

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно чуть модифицировать первый вариант [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), будет поменьше вычислений.
Чтобы не перебирать заведомо неподходящие

- находим первое число z из диапазона [100:999], делящееся нацело на 7
- В цикле по n от z до 999 c шагом 7:
- проверяем, делится ли на 7 сумма цифр n. Если да, суммируем

как-то так

Comment: предлагаю ещё более быстрый вариант. 

    program megafast;
    begin
      writeln('133, 266, 322, 329, 392, 399, 455, 511, 518, 581, 588, 644, 700, 707, 770, 777, 833, 966');
    end.

Comment: Это уже читерство ))))

Comment: @KoVadim, и легким движением руки программа превращается... программа превращается... в элегантный райтэленчик.

Comment: нормальный компилятор кстати должен и привести эту задачу к такому виду. Для фортрана когда то подобное существовало.

Comment: В принципе, при отсутствии ввода и системных вызовов компилятор может (и по-хорошему должен) провести все вычисления в compile-time.

Comment: @Ekkertan: почему читерство? Где предел оптимизации?

Answer (score 5):

Есть два очевидных пути.

1) Идите от чисел:

Цикл по `n` от 100 до 999:

- получить остаток при делении `n` на 7, если не 0, перейти к следующей итерации
- получить сумму цифр `s` числа `n`
- получить остаток при делении `s` на 7, если не 0, перейти к следующей итерации
- здесь число `n` и его сумма цифр `s` делятся на 7, вывести его

Нужна подпрограмма "получить сумму цифр числа `n`":

завести переменную для текущей суммы, начальное значение 0
цикл пока `n` не 0:

- последняя цифра = остаток от деления `n` на 10, прибавить её к текущей сумме
- убрать последнюю цифру, для этого `n` заменить на частное при делении `n` на 10.

2) Идите от разрядов:

Заведите 3 переменные для каждого из разрядов `r2`, `r1`, `r0`.

Цикл по `r2` от 1 до 9: (именно 1, понятно, почему?)

- Цикл по `r1` от 0 до 9: (а здесь 0)

  - Цикл по `r0` от 0 до 9: (и здесь)

    - сумма цифр `s = r2 + r1 + r0`
    - само число `n = r2 * 100 + r1 * 10 + r0`
    - если остатки при делении на 7 `s` и `n` равны 0, вывести `n`

Answer (score 0):

Есть и такая модификация алгоритма.

1. Задаём цифры первого числа, делящегося на 7:
   `h:=1, d:=0, b:=(106 - 106 mod 7) mod 10;`
2. Задаём цикл while(a<10)...do, в котором:
   2.1. Проверяем условие `(a+b+c) mod 7 = 0`.
   При выполнении - выводим число `(10*a+b)*10+c`,
   а в случае `с<3` - заодно и следующее число `(10*a+b)*10+c+7`.
   2.2. Преобразуем биты (с учётом п.2.1):
   `if c<3 then Inc(c,4) else Dec(c,3);`
   `b:=(b+1) mod 10; if b=0 then Inc(a);`